# Mapping ActiveRecord as dynamic key value pair on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to map ActiveRecord query as a key value pair

I want to get the `json_result`s in the form

```
{ "16": "2017-10-16T17:04:51.000Z" }
```

But the below code fetches the results in the form

```
{ "id": 16, "date": "2017-10-16T17:04:51.000Z" }
```

`r.id: r.started_at` does not work.

```
 @results = Visit.all

 json_results = {
    data: @results.map do |r| {
      id:   r.id,
      date: r.started_at

    } end
  }
```

How to achieve this in Rails, as I am having quite some trouble with this.

Comment: You mean, that you want to build JSON without keys? I'm not sure, that it is a valid JSON.

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: As others have pointed out `{"16",""2017-10-16T17:04:51.000Z" }` is not valid json. Perhaps what you want is an array `["16","2017-10-16T17:04:51.000Z"]`?

Comment: I think it was typo and desired result is `{ "16": "2017-10-16T17:04:51.000Z" }`

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 json_results = {
   data: @results.map do |r|
           { r.id => r.started_at }
         end
 }
```

Example:

```
puts ({4 => "foo"}.to_json)
# {"4":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to use `pluck` with `to_h`:

```
json_results = Visit.pluck(:id, :started_at).to_h
```